# Multiple Regex Replacements in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, replace

I am trying create a Regex-based replacement for an article to automatically convert embedded references (many of them) in posts into the appropriate link and title format.

For example, given this:

```
I have already blogged about this topic ((MY TOPIC ID: "2324" "a number of times")) before.   And I have also covered ((MY TOPIC ID: "777" "similar topics")) in the past.
```

... I want to get this:

```
I have already blogged about this topic <a href='/post/2324'>a number of times</a> before.   And I have also covered <a href='/post/777'>similar topics</a> in the past.
```

I currently have this:

```
/* Does not work */
public static string ReplaceArticleTextWithProductLinks(string input)
{
    string pattern = "\\(\\(MY TOPIC ID: \\\".*?\\\" \\\".*?\\\"\\)\\)";
    string replacement = "<a href='/post/$1'>$2</a>";

    return Regex.Replace(input, pattern, replacement);
}
```

But it seems to return lines that contain `<a href='/post/'></a>` without appending matches instead of $1 and $2.

**Question**:  What is the easiest way to do convert the string #1 above to string #2 above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not capturing the parts of the expression you want to extract.  Try something like this:

```
public static string ReplaceArticleTextWithProductLinks(string input)
{
    string pattern = @"\(\(MY TOPIC ID: ""(.*?)"" ""(.*?)""\)\)";
    string replacement = "<a href='/post/$1'>$2</a>";

    return Regex.Replace(input, pattern, replacement);
}
```

Comment: C# does support the $1/$2 mechanism, but you're right about not capturing any groups. If you update your answer, I'll vote you up.

Comment: Ah yes, you are right. Not sure why I never realized that. Updated.